# Example of natural filtration which is not right-continuous

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, filtrations

Can anyone please give me an example of a process $X$ whose natural filtration satisfies $(\mathscr{F}_{t}^{X_{+}})_{t \ge 0} \neq (\mathscr{F}_{t}^{X})_{t \ge0}$?

Comment: Please, explain the notations and ask the question clearly. What are the assumptions on $X$, $\mathcal{F}^X_t$ and $\mathcal{F}^{X_+}_t$? Is $(\mathcal{F}^X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ the NATURAL filtration of the process $X$? How do you define $\mathcal{F}^{X_+}_t$? Is ti the intersection of $\mathcal{F}^X_t$ over all $s>t$? Do you want an example filtration that is NOT right-continuous? And what have you tried to do?

Comment: let X be a random variable, and  the neutral filteration which is defined as  $\sigma(W_{t},t \in \mathscr{F},s\le t)$ known as $(\mathscr{F}_{t}^{X})_{t>0}$ is not right continuous of  filtration because $(\mathscr{F}_{t}^{X_{+}})_{t>0} \neq (\mathscr{F}_{t}^{X})_{t>0},where(\mathscr{F}_{t}^{X_{+}})_{t>0}= \bigcap_{s>t}^{\mathscr{F}^{X}_{s}} as \mathscr{F}_{t_{+}=\bigcap_{s>t}^{\mathscr{F}_{s}},my question is that if can u please give me an example to proof that its not right continuous .

Comment: Can you state the question clearly please, with LateX formulas correctly displayed ? $X = (X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a process ? The right-continuity depends on the process considered. Do you want an example filtration that is not right-continuous?

Comment: yes =()≥0 is a random variable of a stochastic process W = {W(t), t ∈ T } at time t, I want example please  to proof that the neutral filtration is not right continuous.

Comment: Your question is contradictory. I know what the NATURAL filtration of a process is, but the filtration of a random variable $X$ has no meaning (or it is just the $\sigma$-field generated by $X$). So what are $W$ and $X$? Moreover right-continuity of a natural filtration $\mathcal{F}^X$ means that $\mathcal{F}^X_{t+} = \mathcal{F}^X_t$ for all $t \ge 0$, so four continuous filtrations, you cannot have $\mathcal{F}^X_{t+} = \mathcal{F}^X_t$. So, for the third time, do you ask for an example of filtration that is not right-continuous?

Comment: Your question is contradictory. I know what the NATURAL filtration of a process is, but the filtration of a random variable  has no meaning (or it is just the -field generated by ). So what are  and ? Moreover right-continuity of a natural filtration $\mathcal{F}^X$ means that $\mathcal{F}^X_{t+} = \mathcal{F}^X_t$ for all ≥0, so for continuous filtrations, these two $\sigma$-fields you cannot be different. So, for the third time, do you ask for an example of filtration that is not right-continuous?

Comment: as I know  F_{t_{+}}^{X}=F_{t}^{X} are equal if neutral filtration is right continuous but it's not right continuous and I don't why , yeah I ask for an example of filtration that is not right continuous .

Comment: I finally edited your question that was written very badly and in an incoherent way. I give an answer below. It is not right that I have to insist so much to know what your true question is. My role is not to correct the question before giving and answer. If you do not make efforts, I  will simply vote down the next time.

Comment: this is the first time I try to ask on this  application ,next time I'll try to elaborate more , thank you for helping

Answer (score 2):

Let $(W_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_+}$ be a simple symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}_+$ starting at $0$. Interpolate $W$ linearly on each time interval $[n,n+1]$. This defines a continuous and piecewise affine process $(W_t)_{t \ge 0}$. Its natural filtration satisfies $\mathcal{F}^W_t = \mathcal{F}^W_{\lceil t \rceil}$ for each $t \ge 0$. It is right-discontinuous at each integer time $n$. Indeed, the value of the increment $W_{n+1}-W_n$ is  unknown at time $n$ (since $W_{n+1}-W_n$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}^W_n$) but is known immediatly after (since for every $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, $W_{n+1}-W_n = (W_{n+\epsilon}-W_n)/\epsilon$ is $\mathcal{F}^W_{n+\epsilon}$-measurable).